# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when using localhost

Tags: javascript, ajax, dictionary, cross-domain

I am having some issue when trying to query a layer in AJAX by using localhost. Here is the code:

```
var visitAPI = "http://mhclivemap.appsolutrends.net/api/visits?" +
                "start=" + startDate.value + "&end=" + endDate.value + 
                "&diagnosis=" + mhc_type_select.options[mhc_type_select.selectedIndex].value;

           var heatmapData = [];

           $.ajax({      
                url: visitAPI,
                dataType: "json",
                crossDomain:true,
                success: function (res) {
                    var result = res.visits;
                    var marker;

                    for (var i=0; i < result.length; i++) { // iterate thru each element in array
                        for (var j=0; j < result[i].count; j++) { // repeat for count in element
                            marker = new google.maps.LatLng(result[i].lat,result[i].lon);
                            heatmapData.push(marker);                           
                        }
                    };

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('unable to load this layer, please try again later');
                }
            });
```

From this portion of codes, it return me an error message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load mhclivemap.appsolutrends.net/api/visits?start=2014-03-15&end=2014-04-15&diagnosis=GRP1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin localhost is therefore not allowed access.

I wonder what has caused this problem? Is it because of the localhost? If so, what's the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me, the answer was a live testing server. Pretty sure AJAX requires the content come from the same domain.

Comment: Are you sure that service allows cross-domain calls in the first place?

Comment: @JohnSmith But is there any alternate way to perform this? Maybe like switch the URL header?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Yeah, probably it allows tho

Comment: You're sure that it probably allows CORS? Huh...

Answer (score 0):

The server you are sending the request to must return proper CORS headers in the response, such as Access-Control-Allow-Origin with a value that is either a wildcard or equaling the domain you are making the request from.  Clearly, that is not happening here.  You'll need to ensure the server supports CORS.  If it does, you'll need to ensure your domain is registered.

Comment: Is there any alternate way to achieve this by doing some tricks on the codes?

Comment: You have 3 options:  1.) Proxy the cross-origin requests through a server on a domain you control or a domain your control that is on the same origin as the page making the request.  2.) Ensure CORS is properly implemented on the remote server.  3.) Use JSONP (GET only) but the remote server, again, must participate.  In short, there must be participation from some server to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

XHR is bound to the [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Requests can only be done to resources living in the same domain. Requests to external domains will be blocked by the browser. In your case, you are operating as `localhost` and the request is to `mhclivemap.appsolutrends.net`. Both are on different domains, the browser will block it.

To request from another domain, [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) must be configured on the external domain. This is done by having it send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Without this configuration, the external server will not allow you to fetch data from it.

See http://enable-cors.org/ on how to configure CORS for different servers.

Comment: So what am I supposed to do is to configure the server? Is there any way to achieve this by doing some tricks on the codes?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Xhr cross-origin access issue. [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) is a browser security model to prevent cross domain Xhr calls. (Xhr which created by http:// abc.com can't make a request to http:// sub.abc.com)

Server proxy might be the proper way to solve this cross-origin access issue if you can't control the remote server. Here is a simple server proxy example (PHP):

**Proxy.php** (should be on the same origin as the page making the API call)

```
<?php
  $url = $_GET['remoteUrl'];

  $ch = curl_init();
  $options = [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Google Bot",
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
  ];
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  header("Content-Type: application/json;charset: UTF-8");
  echo $output;
?>
```

**client.html**

```
var visitAPI = "http://mhclivemap.appsolutrends.net/api/visits?" +
            "start=" + startDate.value + "&end=" + endDate.value + 
            "&diagnosis=" + mhc_type_select.options[mhc_type_select.selectedIndex].value;

$.ajax({
    url: "proxy.php?remoteUrl="+visitAPI,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
    }
});
```

If you can control the remote server response, try to use JSONP approach.

**RemoteServer.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['callback'])){
    //set response content-type header in application/javascript
    header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
    //wrap response with a function call, if client try to fetch cross-origin data in jsonp way
    echo $_GET['callback']."(".$response.")";
}else{
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo $response;
}
```

**client.html**

```
var visitAPI = "http://mhclivemap.appsolutrends.net/api/visits?" +
            "start=" + startDate.value + "&end=" + endDate.value + 
            "&diagnosis=" + mhc_type_select.options[mhc_type_select.selectedIndex].value;

$.ajax({
  url: visitAPI,
  dataType:"jsonp",
  success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(response){

  }
});
```

This [API](http://api.wunderground.com/api/8ac447ee36aa2505/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json) also adopt the same strategy to determine what type of response it should return.

[In JSON format](http://api.wunderground.com/api/8ac447ee36aa2505/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json)

[In JSONP format](http://api.wunderground.com/api/8ac447ee36aa2505/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json?callback=test)